# Get JSON with HTTP Authentication with AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I am trying to get a JSON from my hudson url address and authenticate my (Mac OS X) application using the HTTP Authenticate.

Following the example I'm using:

```
// AppDelegate.m
- (void) doSomething {
    [[CommAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:@"/computer/api/json" parameters:nil
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"totalExecutors"]);

    } failure:nil];
}

// CommAPIClient.m
+ (CommAPIClient *) sharedClient {
    static CommAPIClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        _sharedClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:    [appDelegate.hudsonTextField stringValue]]];
    });
    return _sharedClient;
}

- (id) initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self){
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        userName = [appDelegate.userTextField stringValue];
        password = [appDelegate.passwdTextField stringValue];

        [self setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:userName password:password];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I want to get the computer's list to show in my dropdown, but this two lines does not work together:
    [self setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:userName password:password];
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

If I just use the first line, my authetication works, but I receive that error because I try to get a key:

```
2012-02-03 02:43:57.542 HudsonSlave[7523:707] An uncaught exception was raised
2012-02-03 02:43:57.542 HudsonSlave[7523:707] [<NSConcreteData 0x100850000> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key totalExecutors.

2012-02-03 02:43:57.623 HudsonSlave[7523:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSConcreteData 0x100850000> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key totalExecutors.'
```

If use the second line, my authentication will return an error 403.

Anyone could help with problem ?

Thanks and apologize for any errors in english.

Thiago

Comment: What happens when you use both lines, exactly?

Comment: @mattt, the error told me that was missing a content-type, so, I've added a third line:
[self setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];


and the error is: 
Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "text/javascript",
    "application/json",
    "text/json"
)}, got application/javascript" UserInfo=0x100513190 {NSLocalizedDescription=Expected content type {(
    "text/javascript",
    "application/json",
    "text/json"
)}, got application/javascript, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://hudson.concretecorp.com.br/computer/api/json}

Answer (score 14):

I ran into this issue with the Flickr API and ended up subclassing `AFJSONRequestOperation` which turned out to be trivial.  You need only override the class method `defaultAcceptableContentTypes` thusly, for example:

```
+ (NSSet *)defaultAcceptableContentTypes;
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/plain", nil];
}
```

Then in my AFHTTPClient subclass, I just register my subclass as the default HTTP operation class:

```
[self registerHTTPOperationClass:[CCFFlickrJSONRequestOperation class]];
```

UPDATE 2013-09-09 14-52-47:

The method name is now `+ (NSSet *)acceptableContentTypes`

Comment: After trying lot of solutions out there, subclassing AFJSONRequestOperation and overriding defaultAcceptableContentTypes was the cleanest and better work around! THANK YOU!

Comment: It looks like in `AFNetworking 1.0RC1` this method name has changed to  `+ (NSSet *)acceptableContentTypes`

Comment: side note: sometimes also need to add @"text/html"

Answer (score 7):

> "Expected content type {( "text/javascript", "application/json", "text/json" )}, got application/javascript"

Just like the error said, the request was expecting one of `text/javascript`, `application/json`, or `text/json`, but the server sent `application/javascript` (which is an incorrect mime type for JSON).

Either get your server to respond with the correct mime type, or (perhaps easier) manually change the line in `AFJSONRequestOperation` that specifies which mime types are accessible. There's a less hacky alternative to changing the library code that involves subclassing, but that's probably much more trouble than it's worth in your case.

Comment: Just a side note: you don't need to set the `Content-Type` header in `AFHTTPCLient`. That will automatically be set depending on the way your request parameters are serialized.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can now add more content-types easily:

```
[AFHTTPRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html", nil]];
```

Comment: Good Question, Shmidt.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a one-time thing instead of subclassing the whole AFJSONRequestOperation object you can just set the acceptable content types directly to whatever you need:

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = blah blah blah

 [operation setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/plain",@"text/html", nil]];

[operation start];
```

Comment: setAcceptableContentTypes doesn't appear to exist in AFNetworking 1.1

Answer (score 2):

As of AFNetworking 2.0, serialization is no longer a part of RequestOperation classes, and is delegated to Serializer classes. If you use 2.0, you want to do something like this (in general I think it's the best solution to *extend* acceptableContentTypes instead of replacing it - you never know what base values it will have in future AFNetworking SDK versions):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *requestManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSMutableSet *contentTypes = [requestManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes mutableCopy];
[contentTypes addObject:@"text/html"];
[contentTypes addObject:@"text/plain"];
// ... etc ...
requestManager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [contentTypes copy];
```

If you decide to use an AFHTTPRequestOperation object directly, just replace "requestManager.responseSerializer" with "myOperationObject.responseSerializer".